# Non-zero vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ has infinitely many subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The proof given in my book says, take all lines passing through origin. They are definitely sub spaces and since there are infinite number of lines through the origin, the number of sub spaces is infinite.

However, I have trouble understanding this. Suppose, the vector space itself is a line through the origin, then what would we do?

Comment: are we talking about affine or linear subspace?

Comment: A line is just a vector space that has one basis vector. For example, all of the $x$-axis is spanned by $\hat x$ when you’re dealing with $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. The result is true if the dimension is atleast $2$. The real line itself is a counter-example since it has only two subspaces.